# Horizontally center a mdl-button

Tags: html, css, button, material-design, material-design-lite

Is there an easy way to horizontally center an `mdl-button`? A button like this:

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect">
  <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>
```

centered only horizontally on a web page without using the `mdl-grid`. Or is the `mdl-grid` the correct way to position thing in general when using MDL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a button is `inline-block`, the easiest way is to apply `text-align: center;` to a parent element. You can do that with the `.center-align` helper class if you don't want to utilize the grid.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
<div class="center-align">
  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </button>
</div>
```